# Set up a Command Line Java error log?

Tags: java, error-handling, jnlp

I have a Download Manager JNLP which is messed up.

I need a way to tell remote users to turn on error logging or somehow send me the error that happened on their Mac or PC.

I've been sending them to their control panel to enable logging and mess around with trace levels etc, and e-mail me, but these are elderly people.

I can't add any error handling to the actual JNLP because it's locked/intellectual property.

I'm thinking there is a command line from MSDOS or Terminal such as "java -enable logging" etc. Just so I can see what the specific JNLP errors are.

Answer (score 1):

Just thought I'd answer my question. You cannot. You can import the error handler libraries and enable error reporting in the code, or you can enable the Java Logger/Tracer through control panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can log all errors and then email it. Ofcourse you have to make sure your package has the requisite dependant libraries